# Need wpf graphcomponent that support heat map with contours

Tags: wpf, graph, heatmap, contour

I am developing a WPF application.

In this application i need to be able to do a filled contour plot which is like at heat map with contours. The image below shows how i need the data visualized:

[image]

I have spent hours trying to find such graph component. I have a telerik license and a sciChart license but none of these support what i need.

Is someone aware of a WPF graph component that can produce an output like on the image above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the contours on top of each other, ordering them by value, starting at the bottom(blue to red, in your example).

You can use a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the container; for drawing the contours, you can use [Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Path markup/StreamGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for answer, had hoped for a component that could do exactly this but i will take a look at your suggestion :).